# UWP/XAML: I'm trying to support dark mode in my app, is there a way to change the cursor/caret color?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

The default caret is almost invisible on a dark background in a TextBox. Is there anyway to change its color?

Comment: If I remember right there's no longer a CaretBrush property or anything you can set and people have been just lightening the background OnFocus to give it the contrast. Which I would agree is kind of dumb and the ability to change the caret color is a feature that should return to UWP.